# <SpringBoot> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2019-12-28 09:49:48.561 ERROR 482 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

1. when I try to start server with command:

   ```
   java -jar jin-alpha-1.0.jar
   ```

under AWS Ubuntu linux server.

In case of trying to local start server was success.

2. The Changed port is suspicious the reason why before changed It work.
   I changed Server port from 8080 to 80.(The reason why AWS http allowed only 80 port)

Local Case : The port of Tomcat server ==> 8080 and 80, Both of them are work. and Stared

AWS Ubuntu : Start with 8080 is work but 80 is not work and Error displayed Above.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.

I Changed Tomcat port from 80 to 8080. so Server started under Aws ubuntu.
(I don't still know why 80 port is not work under Aws Ubutu)

and Add "Custom TCP Rule" with 8080 port Range.

Answer (score 0):

These are called Priviliged ports on *nix systems. The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users are not allowed to run servers on them. This is a security feaure, in that if you connect to a service on one of these ports you can be fairly sure that you have the real thing, and not a fake which some hacker has put up for you.

The normal port number for W3 servers is port 80. This number has been assigned to WWW by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority, IANA.

When you run a server as a test from a non-priviliged account, you will normally test it on other ports, such as 2784, 5000, 8001 or 8080. 
Hope this explains why you cannot run on 80. There are workarounds like running as root. Which I dont recommend as if some hacker gets access to the service then they get root privileges on the box. You need to be careful not running services on such ports.